# Adding last modified date to Google Sites pages

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I am trying to add last modified date to my Google Sites pages. How do I do this? My script below isn't returning any value.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("My own personal page URL");
  var date = page.getLastUpdated();
  return date.getLastUpdated
};
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You SiteApp code is fine but you will get no results from your setup. You have your code being executed in a webapp trigger (doGet()) but not returning a valid object(HtmlService or ContentService). If you are just looking to run the code in the IDE change it to:

```
function logLastModifyDate(){
  var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("My own personal page URL");
  var date = page.getLastUpdated();
  Logger.log(date);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`return date.getLastUpdated`  should be `return date` or as was mentioned on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39662106/1595451) by [Spencer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3014703/spencer-easton) the Logger.log(date) to log the date.